# z-index not working in responsive menu

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have two separate menus for mobile and desktop sites.I have added a very high z-index to this nested menu but it still hides behind other elements and is not displayed at the top. So how do we make this at top of all other elements. 
Here is sample of layout:

```
<nav id="responsive_main_menu">
<div id="navigate-to">Navigate to</div>
                        <ul id="menu-main-menu-1" class="menu">
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home alpha"><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#responsive_main_menu .menu,#responsive_main_menu .menu ul {

z-index: 999999;
}
```

Here is the url showing this problem. Resize the page to smaller version to see the blue menu.http://daccordinc.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`z-index` won't work if you don't have any `position` declared

I added `position: relative;` there and see the difference now

[image]

Comment: Thanks didn't know that it needed to be static. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AhmarAli static is by default, you need to position relative which is kinda static, its just that it respects top, bottom, left and right which static doesn't :) but you can also use absolute, I mean whatever goes there, as am not sure about your layout

Answer (score 3):

You need to apply a position property other than the default value, `static` in order to change the stacking context of an element. Add relative positioning to the below selector:

```
#responsive_main_menu {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999999;
}
```

http://img836.imageshack.us/img836/1389/wgyj.jpg

Answer (score 1):

`z-index` needs `position` to be different than `static` (which is the default) to work.
Try `relative`, it'll work:

```
#responsive_main_menu .menu, #responsive_main_menu .menu ul {
  z-index: 999999;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: you answered too, just missed your answer :) +1